# tcpdump not displaying RSSI

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireshark, tcpdump

I am monitoring Wi-Fi probe requests via tcpdump on Debian and am trying to capture the RSSI (signal strength) of each probe request element. Currently, the output from tcpdump for each probe request looks like this:

```
09:13:17.663057 BSSID:Broadcast DA:Broadcast SA:04:fe:31:67:32:a0 (oui Unknown) Probe Request () [1.0 2.0 5.5 11.0 Mbit]
```

It is missing signal strength and some other elements.

Using another machine with the same version of tcpdump/libpcap and the same arguments to tcpdump, the output includes signal strength (shown below)

```
09:14:51.673753 6.0 Mb/s 2412 MHz 11g -71dB signal antenna 1 BSSID:Broadcast DA:Broadcast SA:b2:b2:b2:b2:b2:b2 (oui Unknown) Probe Request (11n-AP) [1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 9.0 18.0 36.0 54.0 Mbit]
```

Can anyone explain why the RSSI is missing from data payload on the first device and is there any way to capture it?

Per a request from @Spiff, here is a hex dump of one of the packet captures.

```
12:44:40.226564 BSSID:Broadcast DA:Broadcast SA:00:1e:8f:93:3f:60 (oui Unknown) Probe Request (pagefarm) [1.0 2.0 5.5 11.0 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 Mbit]
        0x0000:  4400 0000 9000 0000 7261 3000 0000 0000  D.......ra0.....
        0x0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 4400 0100 0000 0400  ........D.......
        0x0020:  c79d 0300 4400 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....D...........
        0x0030:  4400 0300 0000 0400 0300 0000 4400 0400  D...........D...
        0x0040:  0000 0400 b1ff ffff 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0050:  0000 0000 4400 0600 0000 0400 0000 0000  ....D...........
        0x0060:  4400 0700 0000 0400 0000 0000 4400 0800  D...........D...
        0x0070:  0000 0400 0200 0000 4400 0900 0000 0000  ........D.......
        0x0080:  0000 0000 4400 0a00 0000 0400 3500 0000  ....D.......5...
        0x0090:  4000 0000 ffff ffff ffff 001e 8f93 3f60  @.............?`
        0x00a0:  ffff ffff ffff 4022 0008 7061 6765 6661  ......@"..pagefa
        0x00b0:  726d 0108 0204 0b16 0c12 1824 0301 0332  rm.........$...2
        0x00c0:  0430 4860 6c                             .0H`l
```

Comment: Which OS is the second computer using?

Comment: Which command, exactly, do you use in this case? I use: **tcpdump -n -e -tttt -vvv -i moni0 -s 0 -w moni0.dump "link[0] == 0x80"** which logs to a file called moni0.dump  tcpdump's output, for an interface in monitor mode. This works fine for me, and I do not any other way to do this.

Comment: Both running Debian, the second machine that displays signal strength does have a slightly newer kernel version.

Comment: I use the command "tcpdump -l -n -e -tttt -vvv -I ra0 -s 0 type mgt subtype probe-req"

Comment: I'm not sure why this would or should appear to TCPDump. RSSI is a layer 1 and 2 phenomena.

Comment: @FrankThomas Radio metadata is so critical to debugging 802.11 problems that we long ago added "radio meta data" DLTs to allow the monitor-mode radio to prepend radio metadata as a kind of pseudo-header on the front of every received frame as it passes them up to the packet capture tool.

Comment: ...and tcpdump, the "tcp" in its name nonwithstanding, captures packets at layer 2, and, as Spiff said, Wi-Fi drivers often include the layer-1 radio information in packets supplied to packet capture mechanisms as well.

Answer (score 3):

**[Updated with all the findings from our troubleshooting.

Thanks to tcpdump/libpcap/Wireshark maintainer extraordinaire Guy Harris.]**

`tcpdump` only understands the "Radiotap" (a.k.a `LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIOTAP`, a.k.a `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO`) radio meta-data header format data link type for 802.11 monitor mode.

The `IEEE802_11_RADIO` DLT tells the card/driver to prepend each received frame with an extra "fake" header full of radio meta-data. This is stuff that wasn't transmitted as bits on the air, but was instead read from the state of the radio at the time it received that frame. This information includes the RSSI, the channel the radio was tuned to, the data rate/MCS of the packet, and possibly much more.

If your card & driver support Radiotap, you can specify that you want to capture in this mode by adding `-y IEEE802_11_RADIO` to your `tcpdump` arguments. You can get a list of supported data link types for your `ra0` interface with `tcpdump -i ra0 -IL`, or possibly with `tcpdump -i ra0 -D`. Note that the monitor mode DLTs might not appear if you don't include the `-I` to specify monitor mode. Note also that adding `-I` to put the interface into monitor mode might not work on all systems, so you may need to use the `airmon-ng` script in the `aircrack-ng` open source software package to turn monitor mode on.

It looks like the Ralink driver/chipset on the non-working machine doesn't support Radiotap headers. It apparently only supports the deprecated Prism header format, and a lesser-known variant of Prism headers at that.

You could confirm this theory by checking the DLT of the interface on the working machine (when in monitor mode) using the commands above, and confirming that it's `IEEE802_11_RADIO`.

If confirmed, this means your options come down to things like:

- Update the driver on your non-working machine to make it match the driver on your working machine. Apparently the driver on the working machine supports Radiotap headers. Since you say both machines have the same model USB Wi-Fi adapter, hopefully both adapters truly have the same Wi-Fi chipset inside, so the better driver will work.
- Use Wireshark (or the included command-line tool `tshark`) to do your monitor mode packet captures on the machine with the problem. Wireshark and tshark should know how to parse the variant Prism headers that the "bad" driver supports.
- Capture the link-layer headers with `tcpdump` and parse out the RSSI of the variant Prism header yourself. It will most likely be the little-endian SInt32 at offset 0x44 (decimal 68). It would be more reliable to look for the sequence `4400 0400 0000 0400` and then take the next 4 bytes and consider them an SInt32. In your example captured header, the RSSI value looks like: `b1ff ffff`. That would be `0xffffffb1`, which is the 32-bit two's complement signed integer representation of -79, which is a valid RSSI for a poor-but-still-workable signal strength.
- Use `tcpdump` to capture to a file on the problem machine, but analyze them afterwards using Wireshark or `tshark` on another machine.
- etc.

Comment: `tcpdump -i ra0 -D` will show what DLTs are available on ra0.

Comment: Note that `-I` might not work, in which case the workaround is to use the [airmon-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng) script in [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) to turn monitor mode on.  Your distribution may already have a package for aircrack-ng.

Comment: When I issue `tcpdump -I ra0 -IL` I only see a data link type of PRISM_HEADER (802.11 plus Prism header). Is there any way to get additional DLTs onto my system?

Comment: @kittyhawk Twice now you've reported your arguments to tcpdump and both times you wrote a capital `I` instead of a lower-case `i` in the place where you'd need to put a lower-case `i` to specify an interface. It makes me suspect you're doing it wrong on your actual machine.

Comment: Sorry, I am using a lowercase `i` in my argument. I think autocorrect must have changed it to an uppercase when I was typing it into the comment field.

Comment: @kittyhawk I've never used the Prism header DLT before (I tend to prefer Radiotap), but it looks like it's a radio metadata DLT too. It seems to be capable of reporting RSSI if the card/driver supports it. Maybe you just have a chipset or driver that implements the Prism header poorly. If you post the hex dump of one of your Prism header packets, I'll decode it manually to see if the RSSI is there or not. Maybe it's breaking tcpdump's decoder somehow. http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_PRISM.html

Comment: @kittyhawk I'd also be interested in knowing exactly which Ralink chipset and driver you have on the system that does NOT work, and exactly what Ralink chipset and drive you have on the system that DOES work.

Comment: @Spiff I posted a hex dump of a captured request in the original question text. The non-working device uses the rt2870sta (rt3070) driver. The working device uses the rt2800usb driver. Both are being used with the same Hawking USB adapter (HAWNU1). The working device uses a little newer version of the kernel.

Comment: @kittyhawk Did you get that dump with `-X`? You need `-XX` to include the link-layer headers.

Comment: @Spiff Reposted with the link-layer headers.

Comment: Kittyhawk, it looks like your driver is putting a Prism header on the packets, but it differs in some significant ways from the Prism header format that tcpdump understands. For example, it uses 0x44 everywhere that tcpdump would expect 0x41. And instead of the DIDs being 0x1041, 0x2041, etc., they're 0x10044, 0x20044 (translated from little endian). The place where the RSSI should be contains the value -79, which is a valid RSSI for a poor but still workable signal. @GuyHarris have you seen this version before?

Comment: Unless that's a modified version of tcpdump, there's no Prism header there - standard tcpdump doesn't understand *any* Prism headers, it only understands radiotap headers, it just skips over AVS and Prism headers.  Is this the version of tcpdump that came with Debian?

Comment: @GuyHarris Oops, my mistake. Since the best documentation of the Prism header on the web lives at tcpdump.org, I assumed tcpdump supported the version of the Prism header documented there. http://tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_PRISM.html

Comment: @Spiff Where is the place where the RSSI should be in the link layer header? Can I consistently parse the value out of the header?

Comment: @Spiff the official list of LINKTYPE_/DLT_ values is at http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html; however, that's not a list of values that tcpdump (or Wireshark, or any other packet analyzer that supports pcap or pcap-ng files or capturing using libpcap/WinPcap) necessarily support.

Comment: I've updated http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_PRISM.html to reflect the current reality, in which there are two different flavors of Prism header with different values.  Wireshark currently handles both; tcpdump currently handles neither.

Comment: The machine showing radio information probably has a Wi-Fi adapter with a driver supplying radiotap headers; the other machine has a driver that supplies Prism headers.  Tcpdump handles the (well-specified) radiotap headers (which supply well-defined values); it doesn't handle the (not-at-all-specified) Prism headers (which supply values with no clue as to how they're to be interpreted).

Comment: @kittyhawk I don't know if SU automatically notifies you when someone edits an Answer to your Question, so I just wanted to @-you to let you know that I updated my Answer to include the stuff we've learned from troubleshooting and provide several solutions for your issue.

Comment: @Spiff I've decided to continue to use tcpdump and then parse the RSSI values from the hex dump per your (and @GuyHarris) recommendation. Thanks for the comprehensive analysis and answer.